# How can I display a different icon for each element in ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I use ngFor to iterate through a device list, which then displays the devices in a table. I want to display an icon next to the device name that corresponds to the element. For example, if the element is "mobile phone" then there will be a mobile icon and the next element, camera, will have a camera icon.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of deviceTypes"> 
    <td>{{ item.nameEn }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" title="View" 
    (click)="viewDevice(item._id, item.nameEn)">
        <i class="fa fa-eye clickable"></i>&nbsp;{{
        'btn_elements.view' | translate }}</button>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: [`[ngClass]=""`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) assuming that you have something in your object that relates directly to a corresponding icon class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have a property in your item with the icon name:

`item.icon = 'camera';`

And then set the icon class:

`<i class="fa clickable" [ngClass]="item.icon"></i>`

Or:

Do the mapping inside a function:

`<i class="fa clickable" [ngClass]="getIcon(item._id)"></i>`

```
icons = new Map([[1, 'camera'], [2, 'phone']);

getIcon(deviceId: string): string {
   return this.icons.get(deviceId);
}
```